# How to I attach an email to an other email?

Tags: c#, outlook, email

I have been trying to add an previous email to an new email but cant seem to get that working. I can retrieve all the information from the email but can't attach it to the new email as an attachment.

I have used :

```
 Outlook.MailItem ForwardingMessage = (Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

 Outlook.MailItem SelectedMessage;  
 SelectedMessage = (Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];

 ForwardingMessage.Attachments.Add(SelectedMessage);
```

I'm using C# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 and Outlook 2010.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the problem with that code? What errors are you getting?

Comment: The error states that an object could not be found.

Comment: Please be more precise and post the exact exception message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the attachment type when calling Attachment.Add:

ForwardingMessage.Attachments.Add(SelectedMessage, OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem);

Comment: Thank you for your help.Everything seems to be working just fine now. Instead of taking the email directly i save it to my PC and pulled out of the location i specified. Sorry for this inconvenience.Have a nice day.